# formula that references VBA output does not update (due to latency?)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell (cell A) that contains a formula which counts the unique values from another cell (cell B) referencing VBA function that outputs a comma separated list of values. Because it takes a slightly longer for cell B to generate this list, cell A will display 1 until I go in manually and re-update the cell once the list has appeared in cell A.

Cell A: =csvRange(Range)
Cell B: =CountUnique(Cell A)

this is the csvRange function cell A calls

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
Application.Volatile True
Dim csvRangeOutput
Dim entry As Variant
For Each entry In myRange
    If IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf entry.offset(0, 11) > 1 _
    Or entry.offset(0, 12) > 1 _
    Or (entry.offset(0, 13) > 1 And entry.offset(0, 13) <> "NA") _
    Or (entry.offset(0, 14) > 1 And entry.offset(0, 14) <> "NA") Then
        csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
    End If
Next
csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

I want to investigate into a workaround for this latency issue by any means possible.

Thanks all.

Comment: How is your CountUnique made? I created something small with a dictionary and my cell might take a second to update but still updates regardless.

Comment: `csvRange` could run more quickly if you first read the data into an array and then loop over that, instead of hitting the worksheet 6 times per row.  What size of range are you typically dealing with?